# I get notification in Mac, though App is installed in iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, notifications

There is one App installed in my iPhone, that is news App. Now, whenever I connect my iPhone to Mac, I get notification also in Mac.

What may be the reason ?

I want to get rid of this..

> EDIT 1

I disable it from Preference. But as shown in the following image, I don't know why this App is shown in Mac. It only exists in iPhone.

See App named **NDTV**.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no NDTV mac app (not on their website). Looks like you're receiving notifications via Safari?

Comment: Could you try the suggestions here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180820/suspicious-ndtv-notification-pop-ups-in-my-mac-yosemite-10-10

Answer (score 0):

***Safari > Preference > Notifications***
[image]